# Curious why this recursive code won't work, and exhibits really anamolous behavior in another method

Tags: java, recursion, input, while-loop

New programmer here, having some problems with some code about what I would think is recursion.

```
public static int sum (int a) {
    int input = goodInput(); //get input from below method without having to put its code in this one
    if (input==-1)//so user has the ability to exit at any time
        return a; //when user has finally entered -1, the final sum is sent out
    else; //for scenarios before last input 
    int b = a + input; //adding the newest input to the sum 
    int c = sum(b); //throw the total into the method again until -1 is read
    return c; //once -1 is read, a in that iteration is sent up through every iteration of the method    until the original method gets its return
}
public static int goodInput () { //code to get input of correct type
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);  
    while (!input.hasNextInt()) { //if I put in integer input, the loop should not be entered, but this isn't happening
        System.out.println("Integers only please");
        input.next();
    }
    int finalInput = input.nextInt(); //Finally set good input
    input.close(); //close scanner
    return finalInput; 
}
```

First method here is clearly just a way to get a sum. I know there are multitudes of other ways to just sum some numbers together, I've done a few myself, but when my class had its lesson on methods and wrote it up having something like the code I listed was the first thing I could think of as a solution, rather than what the teacher ended up recommending. Thought it would be a good learning exercise, in any case.

This code doesn't show any errors in eclipse, so I am stumped as to why it refuses to work. Indeed, it produces results I am really curious of; it naturally asks input at the beginning of the program, but when I enter 0, 1, or any other int, despite the scanner actually having an integer, "Integers only please" is printed, followed by Java announcing exceptions at the end of the while loop, at goodInput's calling in sum, at the return of c, and at the execution of sum in the main method, as well as at java.util.NoSuchElementException, java.util.Scanner.throwFor, and at java.util.Scanner.next.

I have very little idea what is happening here; my best guess would be memory issues, but bugs start occuring at the very first occasion! And the code in goodInput works perfectly well when just used as the main method; not sure why it being called by sum would cause problems.

Again, I don't just want some sum method. I just want to know why the code is behaving in this manner, and how an implementation of sum with my approach would actually work.

Comment: What do you have in your main class?

Comment: Just a comment: This is a completely useless piece of code here: `else;`. If you don't need an else-block, don't create one. An if can stand alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not recursion is the problem here, but your `Scanner`. I have to admit that I am not too familiar with the `Scanner` class, but it seems that if you call `input.close()` and then reenter `goodInput` later, your `System.in` is closed. At least, stepping through with the debugger, I found that the line "Integers only please", is printed in the second invocation of `goodInput`. Deleting the line `input.close();` did the trick for me, and your method worked as intended.

I'd suggest you initialize your scanner in the main method, pass it as an argument, and close it in the main method afterwards.

**Edit**: 
The `close` method of the `Scanner` states the following:

> If this
>   scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying
>   java.lang.Readable readable also implements the  java.io.Closeable
>   interface then the readable's `close` method will be invoked.

So, the underlying reader, i.e., System.in, was closed when you called `close` on the `Scanner`.